# Does model underfitting based-on Accuracy matter for imbalanced data?

Tags: deep-learning, imbalanced-data, overfitting-underfitting

I am training a deep learning model on **imbalanced data** for binary classification. I used **binary_crossentropy** for the loss function and **Accuracy** for the metric. When I plotted the loss, I got an underfitting. Is that a problem as my data is imbalanced and the accuracy does not reflect how well the model is?

Comment: If data is imbalanced, then accuracy is obviously not a correct metric to evaluate the model. You need to use Precision or Recall based on your task. If you bother about both precision and recall, you can consider F-score metric too, which is a harmonic means of Precision and Recall.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I understand that accuracy is not used for evaluating the model in case of imbalanced data. Although my model performs well in terms of F1-score I am not able to interpret the cause of underfitting when I plotted the loss.